# Using Phoenix to help to integrate elastic-search and Hbase. When use sqlline.py,to create table, bad happens

Tags: elasticsearch, hbase, apache-phoenix

I follow the instruction [Connecting Hbase to Elasticsearch in 10 min or less](http://lessc0de.github.io/connecting_hbase_to_elasticsearch.html). Everything goes fine before the step: Create a table in Hbase using SQLline. When I type $ $PHOENIX_HOME/hadoop1/bin/sqlline.py localhost  , the terminal shows:

```
znbee@znbee-Aspire-V5-452G:~/phoenix-4.1.0-bin/hadoop1$ bin/sqlline.py localhost
Setting property: [isolation, TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED]
issuing: !connect jdbc:phoenix:localhost none none org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver
Connecting to jdbc:phoenix:localhost
14/12/19 11:35:03 WARN util.Tracing: Tracing will outputs will not be written to any metrics sink! No TraceMetricsSink found on the classpath
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create  interface org.apache.phoenix.trace.PhoenixSpanReceiver Is the hadoop compatibility jar on the classpath?
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.CompatibilityFactory.getInstance(CompatibilityFactory.java:60)
    at org.apache.phoenix.trace.TracingCompat.newTraceMetricSource(TracingCompat.java:40)
    at org.apache.phoenix.trace.util.Tracing.addTraceMetricsSource(Tracing.java:294)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixConnection.<clinit>(PhoenixConnection.java:125)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$9.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1516)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$9.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1489)
    at org.apache.phoenix.util.PhoenixContextExecutor.call(PhoenixContextExecutor.java:77)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.init(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1489)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.getConnectionQueryServices(PhoenixDriver.java:162)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.connect(PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.java:129)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.connect(PhoenixDriver.java:133)
    at sqlline.SqlLine$DatabaseConnection.connect(SqlLine.java:4650)
    at sqlline.SqlLine$DatabaseConnection.getConnection(SqlLine.java:4701)
    at sqlline.SqlLine$Commands.connect(SqlLine.java:3942)
    at sqlline.SqlLine$Commands.connect(SqlLine.java:3851)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sqlline.SqlLine$ReflectiveCommandHandler.execute(SqlLine.java:2810)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:817)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.initArgs(SqlLine.java:633)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:680)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.mainWithInputRedirection(SqlLine.java:441)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:424)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:357)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:445)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.CompatibilityFactory.getInstance(CompatibilityFactory.java:46)
    ... 24 more
```

Comment: what do you mean link is dead?

Comment: http://lessc0de.github.io/connecting_hbase_to_elasticsearch.html/ gives a 404 error.

Comment: sorry , it's good to use now